# Build failed while appending line in source of docker container

Tags: shell, docker, debian, dockerfile, haproxy

I'm working on https://github.com/audip/rpi-haproxy and get this error message when building the docker container:

```
Build failed: The command '/bin/sh -c echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This can be viewed at https://hub.docker.com/r/audip/rpi-haproxy/builds/brxdkayq3g45jjhppndcwnb/

I tried to find answers, but the problem seems to be something off on Line 4 of the Dockerfile. Need help to fix this build from failing.

```
# Pull base image.
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:latest

# Enable Jessie backports
RUN echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Setup GPG keys
RUN gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  8B48AD6246925553 \     
    && gpg -a --export 8B48AD6246925553 | sudo apt-key add - \
    && gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  7638D0442B90D010 \  
    && gpg -a --export 7638D0442B90D010 | sudo apt-key add -

# Install HAProxy      
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install haproxy -t jessie-backports

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/local/etc/haproxy/

# Copy config file to container
COPY haproxy.cfg .
COPY start.bash .

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/haproxy-override"]

# Run loadbalancer
# CMD ["haproxy", "-f", "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash", "start.bash"]

# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Comment: to debug, just do `docker run -it resin/rpi-raspbian:latest /bin/bash` or `docker run -it resin/rpi-raspbian:latest /bin/sh` and then launch `echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list` and see the more precise error message you get, if the error is later, go on with the next commands

Comment: by the way, what gives `docker run -it resin/rpi-raspbian:latest ls /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @user2915097: In response to the first comment, it builds successfully and spit no error on Docker for Mac, the problem occurred when Docker Hub is trying the automated build, which fails: https://hub.docker.com/r/audip/rpi-haproxy/builds/brxdkayq3g45jjhppndcwnb/

Comment: @user2915097: In response to the second comment, this is the message the console:
`/etc/apt/sources.list` and then
`/usr/bin/entry.sh: line 93: fg: job has terminated`

Comment: so post the line 93 of /usr/bin/entry.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logs:

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

It's complaining about an invalid binary format. The image you are using is a Raspberry Pi image, which would be based on an ARM chipset. Your build is running on an AMD64 chipset. These are not binary compatible. I believe this image is designed to be built on a Pi itself.

Comment: I'll try building it on Raspberry Pi itself, if that is the case, I'll accept this answer is the best answer.

Comment: Building on the RPi does provide a new set of errors, suggesting it is specific to the chipset I'm working on.